# Change CSS' media queries through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

Is there a way to change a website's actual media queries through javascript ?

I'm developping an app contained in an iframe on my client's websites who recalculate body's width to place a panel in the right side. When the browser is resized, the client's media queries are called and act without taking my iframe into consideration resulting in a messed up layout.

Do you see a way for me to change the clients media queries with javascript so that I can keep the layout clean ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Do you have access to the stylesheets?

Comment: I just have a tag on the website, so I can only do Javascript

Comment: Maybe there's a way of fixing it without changing the media queries. Can you post an image showing the problem (how is the layout messed up)?

Comment: Sorry, nothing is live actually

Comment: The Same Origin Policy prevents pages from accessing contents of an Iframe of a different domain. You probably can't do what you intend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19593526/1324357 We can go to css with document.styleSheets.

Answer (score 0):

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/577002/1275214) there's an example of how load css files dynamicly with javascript. You could combine this with removing the original stylesheet via jquery, like:

```
$("link[rel='stylesheet']").remove()
```

and reload the same css file but with another media (your new media query).